# replace with sed a portion of a string

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a txt file named **foo.txt** with the following lines:

```
asdoij 989sda
asdad214234
ZSH_THEME="ys"
sadd iju9 98 ad a ="gh"
="ys"
```

I want to replace `ys` (on the line #3) with `bar` using sed.

I had try with `cat foo.txt | sed s:ZSH_THEME="(.+)":bar:` wihtout any luck.

Can anybody show me how to do it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to quote sed command and parentheses are considered literal parentheses without extended regex option which needed to be escaped.

Use this sed:

```
> sed 's~\(ZSH_THEME="\)[^"]*\(".*\)~\1bar\2~' file
asdoij 989sda
asdad214234
ZSH_THEME="bar"
sadd iju9 98 ad a ="gh"
="ys"
```

OR for inline editing:

```
> sed -i.bak 's~\(ZSH_THEME="\)[^"]*\(".*\)~\1bar\2~' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes have special meaning in the shell. Quote them if you want `sed` to get them as literal characters:

```
 sed 's/ZSH_THEME="ys"/ZSH_THEME="bar"/'
```

Note that you cannot tell sed "only replace this part of the string" easily, but there are ways:

```
sed '/ZSH_THEME="ys"/s/"ys"/"bar"/' # Using an "address"
```

or

```
sed 's/\(ZSH_THEME="\)ys\("\)/\1bar\2/' # Using captures
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/\(ZSH_THEME="\).*/\1bar"/'
```

with your example

```
kent$  echo 'asdoij 989sda
asdad214234
ZSH_THEME="ys"
sadd iju9 98 ad a ="gh"
="ys"'|sed 's/\(ZSH_THEME="\).*/\1bar"/'
asdoij 989sda
asdad214234
ZSH_THEME="bar"
sadd iju9 98 ad a ="gh"
="ys"
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick. This uses escaped brackets to keep the original parts of the pattern and then just replace the rest.

```
cat foo.txt | sed 's|\(ZSH_THEME=\"\)ys\(\"\)|\1bar\2|'
```

If you want to learn more about sed, this link has a lot to read but it is well worth it.
http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/ZSH_THEME=/ s/ys/bar/' foo.txt
```

cat is not needed with a sed. Because you just change "ys", don't need to remind other thing of the line

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it with `awk`

```
awk -F\" '/ZSH_THEME/ {$2="bar"}1' OFS=\" foo.txt
asdoij 989sda
asdad214234
ZSH_THEME="bar"
sadd iju9 98 ad a ="gh"
="ys"
```